# sbt - Adding a task key defined outside of build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

If I define a SBT task key outside of my `build.sbt` file as a Scala class in the project folder, how can I import that task

So in *./project/MyTask.scala* I have;

```
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._

object MyTask {
  lazy val uname = settingKey[String]("Your name")
  lazy val printHi = taskKey[Unit]("print Hi")
  printHi := { println(s"hi ${name.value}") }
}
```

Then in *./build.sbt* I have;

```
import MyTask._

uname := "Joe"
```

Then when I run `sbt printHi` I get an error that the task cannot be found. Running `show uname` also works. When I define printHi in build.sbt directly without the object import everything works as expected.

I need so somehow add this task to the build.sbt file. How can I do this?

Comment: For better googling experience:
How to define sbt task in a separate file outside of build.sbt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that your expression `printHi := { println(s"hi ${name.value}") }` isn't associated to anything.

First off, everything in sbt is a transformation, in this case (`:=`) overrides any previous setting of `printHi` to the definition you give (`println(s"hi ${name.value}")`). But by not associating that expression (which is a `Setting[Task[Unit]]`) to anything (for instance to a project, or as a value that then gets attached to a project) it just gets evaluated in the construction of the `MyTask` object and then thrown away.

One way to do this is to put that setting (`printHi := println(s"hi ${name.value}")`), in a `Seq[Setting[_]]` that you then pull into `build.sbt`:

**project/MyTask.scala**

```
import sbt._, Keys._

object MyTask {
  val printHi = taskKey[Unit]("prints Hi")
  val myTaskSettings = Seq[Setting[_]](
    printHi := println(s"hi ${name.value}")
  )
}
```

**build.sbt**

```
import MyTask._

myTaskSettings
```

Another way is to define `MyTask` to be a mini plugin that lives in `project/`. You can see an example of this in [PgpCommonSettings](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-pgp/blob/v1.0.0/project/Common.scala).